# 2 dimensional git repository. Dev/test/live plus stacked changes in DB development

Tags: sql-server, git, version-control

Ok, this is a question to see if I can get some help with ideas to solve this.

First of all we work with SQL Server transact scripts so it's not usual coding so for instance feature toggles are hard to implement (possible at all?).

Ok, our problem is this:

- Task 1: Add column to table X
- Task 2: Remove table Y and change the 3 stored procedures associated with that table.
- Task 3: Truncate table Z

And we have three different servers, DEV -> TEST -> PROD.

BUT! Since it's SQL we can implement task 1 on DEV, task 2 on Test and Prod but not on dev and task 3 on only test.

And this can also change of course. So all of a sudden we have to add task 2 on dev or task 3 on prod and so on.

Complicated.

This means that the traditional way of thinking with move a product that you're happy with from DEV to TEST and when the users are happy testing move that full product to PROD. Since we're not talking about "full products" here but instead change sets that should be be implemented on different servers at different times I'm a bit unsure about an existing best practice?

Is there some thought put into this that I can read up on or do you have some great suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your statement "Since it's SQL we can implement task 1 on DEV, task 2 on Test and Prod but not on dev and task 3 on only test". Are you suggesting you may apply changes to Test/Prod they are developed? Consider using feature branches strategy for both db and app work, merging into integration branches when ready.

Comment: Yes, we might have a change implemented on only test and prod and not on dev (for a lot of different reasons).

Comment: IMHO, a manual migration scripts approach (i.e. "tasks") will be a nightmare without knowing the target database state. Consider using model based tools (e.g. SSDT) to facilitate creating deployment scripts. Developing a source control strategy without a defined SDLC will be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow you 100% but the setup you are describing is exactly how my company operates their deployments for SQL Server using git.

We have 3 servers, we just use different names `DEV -> STAGE -> PROD`.

As far as your tasks go, I'm not sure I fully understand your problem.

For us, all changes go through all 3 servers, and always in the same order.

All work is done on the DEV server, when that is completed, the changes are checked in to git.

Then our DBA deploys those changes to STAGE in order to monitor and for QA to run automated tests and regression testing.

If all looks good, then we plan a release date, and deploy the changes to PROD.

Comment: The problem is that our tasks are not always deployed to all of the three servers.
If you have 10 tasks. 1, 2, 5, 7 and 10 can be deployed to the DEV, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 to TEST and finally 1, 5 and 10 to PROD.

This is an old heritage and it's hard to change. Question is if there is a git standard to handle it.